# Gestures for text on image in ios

Tags: ios, image, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add text on image. User can adjust text anywhere on that image. I am using UIRotationGestureRecognizer, UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer. But the problem is the text moves all over in my view when I do gestures. I want it to move, zoom, rotate on just that imageview. Please Help. for that I have taken one UIView in main view. Then UIImageView inside that subview and UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

```
  [self buildAgreeTextViewFromString:NSLocalizedString(str,@"\UserName\xgdfg\" #<ts>#") forRow:indexPath.row];

- (void)buildAgreeTextViewFromString:(NSString *)localizedString forRow:(long)row
{
    // 1. Split the localized string on the # sign:
    NSArray *localizedStringPieces = [localizedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];

    // 2. Loop through all the pieces:
    NSUInteger msgChunkCount = localizedStringPieces ? localizedStringPieces.count : 0;
    CGPoint wordLocation = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < msgChunkCount; i++)
    {
        NSString *chunk = [localizedStringPieces objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([chunk isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            continue;     // skip this loop if the chunk is empty
        }

        // 3. Determine what type of word this is:
        BOOL isTermsOfServiceLink = [chunk hasPrefix:@"<ts>"];
        BOOL isPrivacyPolicyLink  = [chunk hasPrefix:@"<pp>"];
        BOOL isLink = (BOOL)(isTermsOfServiceLink || isPrivacyPolicyLink);

        // 4. Create label, styling dependent on whether it's a link:
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:13.0F];
       // label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f];
        label.text = chunk;
        label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        label.userInteractionEnabled = isLink;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.tag = row;

        if (isLink)
        {
            //label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

          //[self.view setBackgroundColor: [self colorWithHexString:@"FFFFFF"]];


           label.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(text1_color_hexcode);

            //1D89FF
            //label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

            // 5. Set tap gesture for this clickable text:
            SEL selectorAction = isTermsOfServiceLink ? @selector(tapUserName:) : @selector(tapPost:);
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:selectorAction];
            [label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
            tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            tapGesture.delegate = self;
            // Trim the markup characters from the label:
            if (isTermsOfServiceLink)
                label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<ts>" withString:@""];
            if (isPrivacyPolicyLink)
                label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<pp>" withString:@""];
        }
        else
        {
            label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        }

        [label sizeToFit];



        if (cell.notificationTxt_view.frame.size.width < wordLocation.x + label.bounds.size.width)
        {
            wordLocation.x = 0.0;               // move this word all the way to the left...
            wordLocation.y += label.frame.size.height;  // ...on the next line

            NSRange startingWhiteSpaceRange = [label.text rangeOfString:@"^\\s*"
                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
            if (startingWhiteSpaceRange.location == 0)
            {
                label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:startingWhiteSpaceRange withString:@""];

                [label sizeToFit];
            }
        }

        //CGFloat y = (cell.notificationTxt_view.frame.size.height - label.frame.size.height)/2;

        label.frame = CGRectMake(wordLocation.x,
                                 wordLocation.y,
                                 label.frame.size.width,
                                 label.frame.size.height);

        [cell.notificationTxt_view addSubview:label];

        wordLocation.x += label.frame.size.width;
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld",row);
    if(row==[notificationArray count]-1)
    {
           chekScrolling=NO;
    }
}
```